# trying to display divs horizontally - asked before I know but can't get it working

Tags: html, css, css-float, sass

I'm trying to format my css properly, to display two divs horizontally. The first div contains 3 divs, which looks good, like this, on the left of the screen:

[image]

You can see my code below.

Now I'm trying to get div4, image2, to fill that big white space.

But I just don't get it. I've tried lots of stuff from this site - overflow:hidden;, clear-both -  but the best I can get is the image appearing on the right, ok, but below the baseline of #character_and_bubbles - not in the space I want. Any help please?

My markup code:

```
<div id = "character_and_bubbles">

 <div id = "top_bubble_div">
  <div id="top_bubble">
   bubble text here
  </div>
 </div>

 <div id = "p_mechanic">
  mechanic image here
 </div>

 <div id = "right_bubble_div">
  <span id="right_bubble">
   bubble text here
  </span>
 </div>
</div>


<div id="image2">
    # how do I position this image in the big white space?
</div>
```

And my Sass:

```
#character_and_bubbles {
margin-top:80px;

#top_bubble_div {
#top_bubble {
    background-color: #fff0a0;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,.5), hsla(0,0%,100%,0));
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,.5), hsla(0,0%,100%,0));
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,.5), hsla(0,0%,100%,0));
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,.5), hsla(0,0%,100%,0));
    background-image:         linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,.5), hsla(0,0%,100%,0));
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px hsla(0,0%,100%,.5),
                3px 3px 0 hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
    color: #333;
    display: inline-block;
    font: 16px/25px sans-serif;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px hsla(0,0%,100%,.5);
}

#top_bubble:after, #top_bubble:before {
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid #fff0a0;
    bottom: -25px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 475px;
}
#top_bubble:before {
    border-right: 25px solid hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
    bottom: -28px;
    right: 472px;
}
}

#p_mechanic {
  padding:20px;
  float:left;

}


#right_bubble_div {
padding:20px;

#right_bubble {
    background-color: #fff0a0;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,.5), hsla(0,0%,100%,0));
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,.5), hsla(0,0%,100%,0));
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,.5), hsla(0,0%,100%,0));
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,.5), hsla(0,0%,100%,0));
    background-image:         linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,.5), hsla(0,0%,100%,0));
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px hsla(0,0%,100%,.5),
                3px 3px 0 hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
    color: #333;
    display: inline-block;
    font: 16px/25px sans-serif;
    width: 282px;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px hsla(0,0%,100%,.5);
}

#right_bubble:after, #right_bubble:before {
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid #fff0a0;
    bottom: 68px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 332px;
}
}
}

#image2{
/* how do I get this to fill that big white space? */
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Are you giving us CSS, Sass or LESS?

Comment: I actually inherited this project from someone else, but I think it's Sass..in fact, sure of it - just checked and there 'sass-rails' in the gem file. How did you suspect it was Sass? Is that what all that wibkit-linear is about?

Comment: The nested `{`s are a dead giveaway for some kind of CSS pre-processor. I threw it through http://sassmeister.com/ to see if it would compile to CSS and it did.  If you provide CSS, more people will be able to help you.

`-webkit-linear-gradient` and its friends are browser specific extensions - probably obsolete but YMMV. It seems like you've got a lot of research ahead of you on this project. MDN is your friend: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move `<div id="image2">` above the rest of the content in the source order.  In its current position, it's rendered below the other content.

For example:

```
<div id="image2"># how do I position this image in the big white space?</div>
<div id="character_and_bubbles">
    <div id="top_bubble_div">
        <div id="top_bubble">bubble text here</div>
    </div>
    <div id="p_mechanic">mechanic image here</div>
    <div id="right_bubble_div">
        <span id="right_bubble">bubble text here</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

You also need to give it a height - either by filling it with content or with `height: 300px;`.  Otherwise the browser renders it as empty / no dimensions.

http://jsfiddle.net/sTvGx/3/

But if your #image element is just there to hold a background image (non-semantic), why not make it a background element on the parent of all those divs, like the body?

I've assumed that you've provided Sass instead of CSS.

Comment: Thanks for that, you've fixed my problem! Although it's a bit annoying that the image on the right has to be first in order, in the markup. Why can't it just work from left to right, like everything else in life? (and the way I think it's been working in my sass, css up to now)

Comment: The short answer is that browsers render top down first, **then** left-to-right.